# A good memoryless elevator strategy?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, statistics

I have a skyscraper with N floors and an elevator. When people arrive on a floor they push the button of their desired destination. So in real time the elevator robot keeps a list of orders, each entry having an origin floor, a destination floor, a time stamp, and a flag telling the robot if the person has been picked up and is now a passenger. I need a good strategy for bringing many people to their destinations fast. But not too complicated at first. It should be memoryless, i.e. the decision should only depend on the current list of orders.

If the time now is t and the elevator is at floor x(t) it must decide whether to go up one floor or down one floor. When it arrives at a floor it stops and opens the door if and only if somebody has ordered that floor as an origin and is not a passenger or destination and is a passenger. But regardless it reconsiders where to go next.

Is a good strategy known? Not to say optimal? The criterion of optimality? It should complete the greatest number of orders in the shortest amount of time.

My only idea so far is to use center of gravity: If xi is the origin and yi the destination of order i, and pi the passenger flag, let z = 1/n sum( (1-pi)xi + piyi ). Then if z < x(t) we go down one floor, otherwise up. But I worry that this could result in a deadlock, perpetually going up and down between floors x and x+1.

Edit. One more thought. One should consider the age of an order. If ti is the time stamp of order i, one should put greater weight on this order if (t - ti) is large. So a weighed center of gravity? Let ai = t - ti and a = sum(ai). Then z = 1/a sum( ai((1-pi)xi + piyi) ).

Edit 2. One should also consider inertia. If the elevator is on its way up the decision might differ from that when it's going down. But I don't know how to take this into account. An inertia strategy might be to never reconsider where to go until the elevator has stopped on a floor. And it only does so if somebody is getting on or off.

Edit 3. Another consideration is load. The elevator doesn't know how many people are on board, but it knows the current load. If that load approaches max it should give priority to bringing people to their destinations rather than picking up more. But how exactly?

Comment: Have you ever noticed that when an elevator arrives at a floor there's an indicator as to which direction it's going, and if you get on it it doesn't change direction until the last destination in that direction has been reached?  Perhaps that's a good default.  You could certainly try alternate strategies, and contrast them by measuring things like the average and variance of the amount of time it takes customers to reach their destination.  Having both measures would imply you're consistently getting people where they want to go quickly.

Comment: If you're seeking an "optimal" solution, you're going to have to be careful in defining what you mean by optimality in a stochastic context.  Expected values can be very misleading if treated as predictions.

Comment: @pjs Yes I have noticed. There seems to be a standard strategy to that effect. But was it adopted because it's simple and safe or because somebody was able to prove something concerning efficiency?

Comment: Define what you mean by efficiency.  Then test different configurations against your definition.

Comment: This is not a purely mathematical matter. If you are aboard a rising elevator and it stops short of your floor and starts to descend, you are likely to (a) get upset (not helpful for you or your fellow passengers) and/or (b) assume a malfunction (and perhaps push the emergency button). This would likely outweigh the perceived gains of more expeditious delivery using a less predictable (by the rider) algorithm.

Comment: @prubin There will be a video camera onboard so I can enjoy the panic that breaks out. If somebody pushes the e button a loud boom is heard and the elevator starts shaking violently.